# Are "Yet" and "However" synonymous?

Tags: meaning-in-context, coordinating-conjunctions

It is quite common to use "yet" and "however" in contrastive constructions, but l am not certain if they have the same sense.

1. John failed. **Yet**, he's tried his best.
2. John failed. **However**, he's tried his best.

My question is, is there any difference in meaning between the two constructions mentioned above?

Comment: [Why is there no comma after _yet_ and what does yet mean compared to _however_ ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290230/why-is-there-is-no-comma-after-yet-what-does-it-mean-compared-to-however-an) is definitely a duplicate question, but I've not C-Vd as the answer here is better. However, this answer doesn't address the issue of the the comma after sentence-initial _yet_.

Comment: Synonyms have different distributions. Some are interchangeable in many sentences with little or negligible change in meaning; with others, the overlap may be tiny. What 'negligible' means here is open to debate, as is whether minor adjustments to say punctuation disqualify synonymity. // I've seen mainly say (1') _John failed. Yet he's tried his best._ Does this mean 'though' is a closer synonym? This may well be a UK style preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crabb's [Synonymes](https://archive.org/details/crabbsenglishsyn008421mbp/page/n441/mode/2up) [sic] has the following entry which explains the difference between these synonymous terms:

> However, Yet, Nevertheless, Notwithstanding.
>
> These conjunctions are in grammar termed adversative, because they
> join sentences together that stand more or less in opposition to each
> other.
>
> *However* is the most general and indefinite; it serves as a conclusive deduction drawn from the whole. "The truth is, *however*,
> not yet all come out"; by this is understood that much of the truth
> has been told, and much *yet* remains to be told: so likewise in
> similar sentences, "I am not, *however*, of that opinion"; where it is
> implied either that many hold the opinion or much may be said of it,
> but, be that as it may, I am not of that opinion: "however, you may
> rely on my assistance to that amount"; that is, at all events, let
> whatever happen, you may rely on so much of my assistance: however, as
> is obvious from the above examples, connects not only one single
> proposition, but many propositions either expressed or understood.
>
> *Yet*, *nevertheless*, and *notwithstanding* are mostly employed to set two specific propositions either in contrast or direct opposition
> to each other; the latter two are but species of the former, pointing
> out the opposition in a more specific manner. There are cases in which
> *yet* is peculiarly proper, others in which *nevertheless*, and others in which *notwithstanding* are preferable.
>
> *Yet* bespeaks a simple contrast; "Addison was not a good speaker, *yet* he was an admirable writer; Johnson was a man of uncouth manners, *yet* he had a good heart and a sound head"; *nevertheless*
> and *notwithstanding* could not in these cases have been substituted.
>
> *Nevertheless* and *notwithstanding* are mostly used to imply effects or consequences opposite to what might naturally be expected to
> result. "He has acted an unworthy part, *nevertheless* I will be a
> friend to him as far as I can"; that is, although he has acted an
> unworthy part, I will be no less his friend as far as lies in my
> power.
>
> "*Notwithstanding* all I have said, he still persists in his own
> imprudent conduct; that is, all I have said *notwithstanding* or not
> restraining him from it, he still persists. "He is still rich,
> *notwithstanding* his loss"; that is, his loss *notwithstanding*, or *not standing* in the way of it, he is still rich. From this resolution of the terms, more than from any specific rule, we may
> judge of their distinct applications, and clearly perceive that in
> such cases as those above cited the conjunctions *nevertheless* and
> *notwithstanding* could not be substituted for each other, nor *yet* for either: in other cases, *however*, where the objects are less
> definitely pointed out, they may be used indifferently. "The Jesuits
> piqued themselves always upon their strict morality, and *yet*
> [*notwithstanding* or *nevertheless*] they admitted of many things not
> altogether consonant with moral principle. You know that these are but
> tales, *yet* [*notwithstanding*, *nevertheless*] you believe them."